# Spark - save RDD to multiple files as output

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a `JavaRDD<Model>`, which i need to write it as more than one file with different layout [one or two fields in the RDD will be different between different layout].

When i use `saveAsTextFile()` its calling the `toString()` method of Model, it means same layout will be written as output.

Currently what i am doing is iterate the RDD using `map` transformation method and return the different model with other layout, so i can use saveAsTextFile() action to write as different output file.

Just because of one or two fields are different , i need to iterate the entire RDD again and create new RDD then save it as output file.

**For example:**

**Current RDD with fields:**

RoleIndicator, Name, Age, Address, Department

**Output File 1:**

Name, Age, Address

**Output File 2:**

RoleIndicator, Name, Age, Department

Is there any optimal solution for this?

Regards,
Shankar

Comment: U need same data in 2 files in 2 different formats is it?

Comment: @VijayInnamuri : Kind of , file 1 will have few fields from the RDD and FIle 2 will have few fields from the RDD and few fields can be same for both files.

Comment: @VijayInnamuri : yes , basically i am looking for same data needs to be written in 2 files with 2 different formats ? is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `foreach`, not `collect`.

You should define your function as an actual named class that extends `VoidFunction`. Create instance variables for both files, and add a `close()` method that closes the files. Your `call()` implementation will write whatever you need.

Remember to call `close()` on your function object after you're done.

Comment: I have tried this on my local machine and its working fine on standalone mode with few records. But what if i want to write the same on `HDFS` on Hadoop YARN Cluster instead of using local file system using `FileWriter` Class and with millions of records? Also, if i use Local File System on Cluster will it override any records when we use multiple threads [hadoop Cluster]?

Comment: when you say class that extends VoidFunction, VoidFunction is an interface. DO you want me to create interface or class?

Comment: @Shankar: you need to implement an interface to use it. I used "extend" in a generic term (and if you were using Scala, that would be the keyword you'd use).

Comment: One thing that I realized after posting this is that `foreach` will execute in the cluster, so you may end up with files sprinkled around the cluster. You may need to iterate partitions at the master node.

Comment: Finally, please don't accept an answer unless it actually solves your problem.

Comment: I got it.. and it solved my problem, that's why i accepted the answer. Writing into local file system is intermediate solution , anyway `foreach` is the answer which i was looking..

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with Pair RDD.
Pair RDD can be stored in multiple files in a single iteration by using Hadoop Custom output format.

```
rdd.saveAsHadoopFile(path, key.class, value.class,CustomTextOutputFormat.class, jobConf);


public class FileGroupingTextOutputFormat extends MultipleTextOutputFormat<Text, Text> { 
  @Override
  protected Text generateActualKey(Text key, Text value) {
    return new Text();
  }

  @Override
  protected Text generateActualValue(Text key, Text value) {
    return value;
  }
// returns a dynamic file name based on each RDD element
  @Override
  protected String generateFileNameForKeyValue(Text key, Text value, String name) {
    return value.getSomeField() + "-" + name;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my question with what i am expecting? is it possible using saveAsHadoopFile()? In your code i dont see anywhere you are specifying different layouts.

Comment: It does not answer the question